# Как добиться плавности

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть слайдер на всю ширину,у которого эффект перехода это `scale , background-posotion` увеличение хорошо работает,а вот позиция подтормаживает

```
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1)  ;
                  background-position:0.1% 0.1%;

    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1)  ;
                  background-position:0.1% 0.1%;
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Тут пример рабочий https://jsfiddle.net/aLafc4pn/2/

Comment: попробуй поиграться с временем исполнения. Подвисания могут быть из-за 1) Большого объекта прорисовки 2) Большого кол-ва одновременно прорисовываемых объектов 3) Слишком большое кол-во анимации на единицу отрисовки. К сожалению, я не нашел проблемы т.к. на фидлере идет достаточно плавно

Comment: Я к тому,может копать в сторону js, а не с помощью css анимацию делать?

Comment: @zkolya в твоем случае не имеет смысла делать анимацию на js. Даже вероятнее хуже станет. Потому что обработка анимации свойства transform происходит не в основном потоке, а в потоке компоновщика. Если честно не заметно какие-то тормоза на примере с фидла. Но можно для обработки анимации попробовать применить свойство [will-change: transform](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-will-change/). Правда с поддержкой ie у него не ахти. Если коротенько и на русском то [тут](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/animations/animations-and-performance#css-vs-javascript-performance)

Comment: Спасибо,попробую

Comment: Попробуйте поиграть с `transform: translate3d()`, ваши тормоза от попиксельного движения, в то время как translate прорисовывает промежуточные значения

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий Artem Gorlachev ближе всех к правде.

`Transform`-методы используют **аппаратное ускорение**, потому анимация с их использованием максимально гладкая.

Пример **С** использование `Transform`-методов:
http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/OyKXyK

Пример **БЕЗ** использование `Transform`-методов:
http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/WQVxQQ

Переводите вашу анимацию на transform-методы (scale, translate и др.) и будет всё выглядеть гладко.